# Jquery search filter - display default message when no results found

Tags: jquery, filter, message, default, keyup

I'm currently building a page where a search field acts as a filter, just as follow :

```
// Custom case insensitive selector
jQuery.expr[':'].Contains = function(a,i,m) { 
    return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase())>=0;
};

// Search field filter
var $section = $('section');

$('#search').keyup(function() {
    var input = $(this).val();

    if(input) {
        $section.hide();
        $("section:Contains('"+input+"')").show();
    }
    else {
        $section.show();
    }
});
```

It works perfectly fine, but there is one issue that I'd like to solve. When the entered string is not found in all the existing `<section>`, the page remains **blank**.

My question is then quite simple, how could I display a default message on my page when no results are found by the filter? Something like a simple `<p>` explaining that "no results were found".

The idea is to display it only **once** as long as the string is not found.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up doing the following thing :

Creating my error message at the end of the list.

```
<p id="noresults">Error message.</p>
```

Showing/hiding it when needed.

```
// Search field filter
var $section = $('section');
var $noresults = $('#noresults');

$noresults.hide();

$('#search').bind('keyup', function() {
    var input = $(this).val();

    if(input) {
        $section.hide();
        var result = $("section:Contains('"+input+"')");

        if(result.length) {
            $noresults.hide();
            result.show();
        } else {
            $noresults.show();
        }
    }
    else {
        $noresults.hide();
        $section.show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the length of matched elements first.

```
var elements = $("section:Contains('"+input+"')");
if(elements.length) //Found
    elements.show();
else
    //display a message
    $("body").append("<p>No results were found.</p>");
```

Comment: note: it would be nice to remove or hide the message somewhen also (but that's a task for the asker)

Comment: Thanks! The main concern here is that the message is appended as soon and as long as the string is not found, which displays it several times.